# Only Run Startup File When Launching IPython Kenel from Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm writing a startup script for users of my Jupyter Lab extension that customizes the pandas dataframe output display using a [formatter](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#formatters-for-third-party-types). The formatting only makes sense in the context of Jupyter Lab, but because the file is in the user's `.ipython/profile_default/startup` folder, it gets executed every time a IPython kernel is started.

I have tried using `get_ipython().__class__.__name__`, however  'ZMQInteractiveShell' is returned both in JupyterLab, Jupyter Notebooks, and VScode. I'm specifically looking for the case where the user is in Jupyter Lab.

Does anyone know how to detect if the IPython kernel was started by launching Jupyter Lab and either 1) preventing the startup file from running all together, or 2) just casing in my startup file itself to not load the formatter when it wasn't started through Jupyter Lab?

My startup file:

```
try:
    import pandas as pd
    
    def df_formatter(obj):
        return f'<div><div onclick="console.log(\'You are in Jupyter Lab\'">In Jupyter Lab?</div> {obj.to_html()}</div>'

    html_formatter = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/html']
    html_formatter.for_type(pd.DataFrame, df_formatter)
except:
    print('Unable to run startup script')
```